# Return values were not extracted in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
def get_dept_class_type
  departments, classifications, types = [["-- select one --"]] * 3

  Department.all.each do |d|
    departments << d.name
  end

  Classification.all.each do |c|
    classifications << c.name
  end

  Type.all.each do |t|
    types << t.name
  end

  return departments, classifications, types
end

def new
 @departments, @classifications, @types = get_dept_class_type
end
```

Hello guys,

above is my code in Ruby to assign the return values from "get_dept_class_type" function to "def new" instance variables. The problem is, the return values from the "get_dept_class_type" function were not extracted, So all instance variables have the same values. Each instance variable is the containing value of a select tag in html form.

The values of department, classification, type select tags have these the same content:

- Information Technology
- Administrative Department
- Internal Use
- Top Secret
- Confidential
- Public
- Policy
- Procedure Manual

Please it help me to figure this out. Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main problem is -

```
 departments, classifications, types = [["-- select one --"]] * 3
```

changed it to -

```
departments, classifications, types = Array.new(3) { ["-- select one --"] }
```

Lets debug it :-

```
([[]] * 3).map(&:object_id) # => [72506330, 72506330, 72506330]
```

but

```
Array.new(3) { [] }.map(&:object_id) # => [76642680, 76642670, 76642520]
```

You can see, that all the inner objects are basically same object. Basically you have created an array of array, say `a`, where all the element arrays are same object. Thus if you have modified, say `a[0]`, you can see the same change when you would inspect `a[1]` or `a[2]`. But if you do create the same array of array, `a` as , `Array.new(3) { [] }`, then each inner element array of `a`, will be different object. Thus if you say modify `a[0]`, then `a[1]` and `a[2]` will be intact.

Worth to read [`Common gotchas`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-c-new-label-Common+gotchas).

Comment: How is this different, in both cases `departments` and others get assigned `["-- select one --"]`

Comment: @saurabh Your question is confusing to me.. Could you be specific ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit Thanks a lot! Yes, I made a mistake. I thought an array of array would be appropriate. Its behaving now accordingly. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, now its clear from your edited answer, Thanks for making it more clear.